# JPA best pattern to merge/over-write a record set

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying to find the best pattern for merging/over-writting a record set with JPA.

Say we have a record set in the DB

```
ID  user_id  fk_id
 1        2   10
 2        2   20
 3        2   30
 4        2   40
```

Now let's say I get the new list of fk_id's for user_id 2 (10,20,50,60)
What I think should happen is, my DB should look like this

```
ID  user_id  fk_id
 1        2   10  >>untouched
 2        2   20  >>untouched
 3        2   30  >>DELETED
 4        2   40  >>DELETED
 5        2   50  >>inserted
 5        2   60  >>inserted
```

So is there a Clean pattern to do this? or are loops just the right way?

## EDIT

What i'm trying to do in reality is, I have a list of DTOs and i need to update the DB based on the DTO's.

- If record exists in a DTO list and DB >> do nothing
- If record exists in a DTO list but not in DB >> create a new record
- If record does not exist in a DTO list but does exist in DB >> delete it.

Comment: The first question that comes to mind is why you manage this relation yourself via a separate entity, instead of using a List (with @OrderColumn, if that matters)

Comment: the relation does not necessarily need to be keys to another table. it could just be a list of codes,or a list of lookups that your are trying to maintain, without deleting and re-inserting everytime.
the question is about how do you just maintain deltas.

Comment: If it's not an entity, you use an `@ElementCollection`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your (vague) question correctly, you are looking for something like `OrphanRemoval`. It is an option in JPA Relationships makes it easy to delete child entries when they get removed from a parent entity.

Doc Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/

A good guide on OneToMany / ManyToOne relationships: [The best way to map a @OneToMany relationship with JPA and Hibernatey](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code I ended up using to merge my DTO list with the domain Entities

```
public void loadUserAdGroupTable(SampleTableEntity sample, Set<sampleDTO> latestValues) {

    Set<LinkTableEntity> existingValues = getExistingValues(sample.getId());
    
    
    Set<LinkTableEntity> deleteList = existingValues.stream()
                                            .filter(entity-> ! latestValues.stream()
                                                                    .anyMatch(dto->dto.getFkId().equals(entity.getFkId()))
                                            ).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
    Set<LinkTableEntity> insertList = latestValues.stream()
                                                    .filter(dto ->existingValues.size() == 0 ||  !existingValues.stream()
                                                            .anyMatch(entity->dto.getFkId().equals(entity.getFkId()))
                                                    ).map(dto -> { 
                                                                  LinkTableEntity entity = new LinkTableEntity();
                                                                        entity.getFkId(String.valueOf(dto.getFkId()))
                                                                             .setSampleId(sample.getId);
                                                                    return entity;
                                                                })
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());


    log.debug("Deleting LinkTableEntity Entities [{}]", deleteList);
    log.debug("Inserting LinkTableEntity Entities [{}]", insertList);
    
    
    linkRepository.deleteInBatch(deleteList);
    linkRepository.saveAll(insertList);
    
}
```